# Obtain unique/unrepeated values from a List

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist

I have an ArrayList `tmp_list` which might contain repeated values. I aim to fill an other ArrayList `filtered_tmp_list` with only one occurence of each value. Here's what I did :

```
ArrayList<String> filtered_tmp_list = new ArrayList<String>();

filtered_tmp_list.add((String) tmp_list.get(0));

for(int i=0; i<tmp_list.size(); i++){
    String cmp = (String) tmp_list.get(i) ;
    int doubled = 0;
    for(int j=0; j<filtered_tmp_list.size(); j++){
        String cmpd = (String) tmp_list.get(j) ;
        if(cmp.compareTo(cmpd)==0){
            doubled ++ ;
        }
    }
    if(doubled==0) filtered_tmp_list.add(cmp);
}
```

My idea was to check if a value -already in `filtered_tmp_list` - is present in `tmp_list` more than once, if so, I do nothing, otherwise : if doubled is equal to zero, it means that values deserves to be inserted into `filtered_tmp_list`.

Well, as you may expect, I am here because I get repeated values... 
What did I miss ?

Thanks.

Comment: compareTo is used for ordering, not for comparing equality

Comment: I know, but that's not at the core of the problem for the moment or is it ?

Comment: What is in `tmp_list`?

Comment: `tmp_list` is a filled-copy of an other List, in short, it is a filled List with repeated values.

Comment: A [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) would be a better solution.

Comment: Have been advised to it, check the answer @DhrubajyotiGogoi. But thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `Set` then a `List`:

```
List<String> ret = new ArrayList<>(new HashSet<>(origList));
```

A `Set` cannot contain duplicate elements; and a `HashSet` is used since `String` implements `.equals()` and `.hashCode()`.

If you want to keep the original order of elements in the initial list, replace the `HashSet` with a `LinkedHashSet`.

(fill empty diamonds with `String` if this is not Java 7)

Edit: see @zerocool's answer as to what was wrong with the original code

Comment: Note that this does not preserve the original ordering of the `List`. If the ordering doesn't matter, then it surely is a simple and effective solution.

Comment: @Gloserio no problem! It has taken some time for me when I began to understand the purpose of `Set`s, but once you read the javadoc, and read it again, you get the point behind them

Comment: @johnchen902 : that would be interesting to know. One thing though : it surely reduces the numbrer of values considerably (like that's any good...).

Comment: @johnchen902 that is a mystery, since String's .compareTo() is consistent with .equals() AFAIK

Comment: @johnchen902 : check out @zerocool's answer below, nothing wrong with the logic, only a stupid mistake...But all fine, got me into discovering a good use of `Set`.

Answer (score 6):

Here you go:

```
Replace below code it works:

for(int j=0; j<filtered_tmp_list.size(); j++){
        **String cmpd = (String) filtered_tmp_list.get(j) ;**
        if(cmp.compareTo(cmpd)==0){
            doubled ++ ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your logic is fine, i hope you can make out where you made the mistake from the code above.

Comment: Sorry for being late, and yes I noticed, I think I need a cry, 90% of my programming difficulties come from typos or stupidies. Well, +1 for having good eyes @zerocool, thanks you !

Comment: Its good to do typos i believe, as long as you can debug them :). Just have a cup of coffe next time when you think your logic is right but code is breaking somewhere:)

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about the order of insertion

```
List<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>(new LinkedHashSet<String>(origList));
```

Comment: Uh, equals returns a boolean!

Comment: yep, must be `!cmp.equals(cmpd)`.